# How to see what privileges are granted to schema of another user

Tags: oracle

Consider the case : In a database , I have two users A and B and their corresponding schema.

I want to know , How can I get the information : what permissions are there for USER A in Schema B .

Consider the case : We have two users and their associated scehmas. We have user A and user B. In A, say we have TB1 TB2,  in B,say we have TBa, TBb.  Now I want to know how can I find what privileges User A has on Schema B.

For example : User A is writing : `select * from B.TBb`   This means USER A is accessing User B's table so , it shows he has SELECT Privilege. I want to know what all privileges User A has on Schema B.

Which query shall be executed to get the list of privileges that User A has on Schema B.

Comment: Consider the case :
We have two users and their associated scehmas.
We have User a and user b
In A, say we have TB1 TB2
In B,say we have TBa, TBb
Now I want to know how can I find what privileges User A has on Schema B.

For eg : User A is writing :
select * from B. TBb

Means USER A is accessing User B's table
so , it shows he has SELECT Privilege


I want to know what all privileges User A has on Schema B.
Is there any Query for that .

Hope , the question was clear to u.

Comment: You can *edit your own question*.  Please do so instead of posting additional info as comments.

Comment: Who is running this putative query: user A, user B or user X who is a DBA?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use these queries:

```
select * from all_tab_privs;
select * from dba_sys_privs;
select * from dba_role_privs;
```

Each of these tables have a `grantee` column, you can filter on that in the where criteria:

```
where grantee = 'A'
```

To query privileges on objects (e.g. tables) in other schema I propose first of all `all_tab_privs`, it also has a `table_schema` column.

If you are logged in with the same user whose privileges you want to query, you can use `user_tab_privs`, `user_sys_privs`, `user_role_privs`. They can be queried by a normal non-dba user.

Answer (score 3):

Use example with from the post of [Szilágyi Donát](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14605206/revisions).

I use two querys, one to know what roles I have, excluding connect grant:

`SELECT * FROM USER_ROLE_PRIVS WHERE GRANTED_ROLE != 'CONNECT'; -- Roles of the actual Oracle Schema`

Know I like to find what privileges/roles my schema/user have; examples of my roles ROLE_VIEW_PAYMENTS & ROLE_OPS_CUSTOMERS. But to find the tables/objecst of an specific role I used:

`SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_PRIVS WHERE GRANTEE='ROLE_OPS_CUSTOMERS'; -- Objects granted at role.`

The owner schema for this example could be PRD_CUSTOMERS_OWNER (or the role/schema inself).

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Login into the database. then run the below query

select * from dba_role_privs where grantee = 'SCHEMA_NAME';

All the role granted to the schema will be listed.

Thanks [Szilagyi Donat](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14605206/revisions) for the answer. This one is taken from same and just where clause added.